# How to set Encoding for HtmlAgilityPack HtmlDocument

Tags: html, encoding, load

Heres my code:

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = hw.Load(@"www.SomeForeignURL.com");
```

The returned HTML page includes characters that look strange, Id like to specify the encoding for the returned document to UTF-8. How can i solve this?

(tried loading the document like so: htmlDoc.Load("url", Encoding.UTF8) but it returned an error saying that the URI is not supported or something like that.)

Answer (score 0):

Its probably not that helpfull but I ran into a problem where the Load() method fails silently, probably failing to detect the format, and worked around it by loading the file into a string first (I used another function to dowload the file). I then used the LoadHTML() method. I'm a year late answering, and I'm using powershell not C# but the hint might still apply.

See second-last line : it simply reads the file into a string and passess to LoadHTML()

```
#  http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2010/03/05/html-agility-pack-rocks-your-screen-

scraping-world/
function DownloadFile {
Param([Parameter(mandatory=$true)]$source , 
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]$destination) 


    $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $wc.DownloadFile($source, $destination)
}

$erroractionpreference = 'stop'
Set-Strictmode -version 2

DownloadFile  "http://someurl/index.php?action=searchplayer&server=0&player=%" "$pwd\all.php"

$types = add-type -Path .\agilitypack\HtmlAgilityPack.dll
$doc = New-Object HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument 
$doc.LoadHtml([string](get-content .\all.html))
$doc
```